# how to verify if SMTP server is working using socket in java

Tags: java, smtp

I want to check if the given SMTP server is working fine by just getting connection and send a hello message and then verify the response code. I don't want to test it by sending email to some address.

I am using java 1.6.

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a socket `Socket s = new Socket("addres_of_smtp_server", stmp_port);`
and then check if the server is alive. Here is the same question in stackoverflow [How to check status of an SMTP server from Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1704749/how-to-check-status-of-an-smtp-server-from-java). Hope it helps.